# Issues Displaying Multiple Angular Material 2 Dialogs

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to generate an error message dialog while another input dialog is open. I suspect multiple Dialogs are supported by the API since there are properties and methods that deal with multiple opened Dialog windows (afterAllClosed, openDialogs, closeAll).

When an error is triggered it attempts to generate the new dialog, but nothing happens. The error message dialog and error message service are registered in the root of the app (app.component.ts).

Is there a special way to invoke a new Dialog when one is already open?

Comment: It should be able to open a dialog within a dialog. Please post your error log or stacktrace.

Comment: There was no error, except for the HTTP Error I am using it to display!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Material version 5.0.3 and Angular 5.1.2 and issue seems to have been resolved.

May have been an issue with the 2.0.0-beta.12.